# How to use inout on array of iVars?

Tags: swift, inout

I'm not quite understanding why the following code does not update the original values of `array1` and `array2`. I'm trying to use `inout` on an array of iVars ...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: instance variables

    var array1: [Int] = [1, 1, 1]
    var array2: [Int] = [2, 2, 2]



    // MARK: lifecycle methods

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var tempArray = [array1, array2]
        performOperationOn(&tempArray)
        print("array1: \(array1)")
        print("array2: \(array2)")
        print("tempArray[0]: \(tempArray[0])")
        print("tempArray[1]: \(tempArray[1])")
    }



    // MARK: private methods

    private func performOperationOn(_ array: inout [[Int]]) {
        array[0][0] = 11
        array[0][1] = 11
        array[0][2] = 11

        array[1][0] = 22
        array[1][1] = 22
        array[1][2] = 22
    }
}
```

...

The above prints out:

```
array1: [1, 1, 1]
array2: [2, 2, 2]
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm expecting:

```
array1: [11, 11, 11]
array2: [22, 22, 22]
```

Printing out tempArray does reveal it is being modified:

```
tempArray[0]: [11, 11, 11]
tempArray[1]: [22, 22, 22]
```

But I really want the OG arrays (array1 and array2) to be the ones being modified ... thoughts?

Comment: `tempArray` copies the contents of `array1`, `array2`

Comment: ok right, Int is a value-type ... interestingly enough, in my actual app I simply changed from a struct to a class and the "Ints" in my above example actually do update and all is well! Thanks for this hint :)

Comment: It's called *copy-on-write*

Comment: @ChrisAllinson What exactly is your usecass here? Using `inout` variables as a substitution for assignment is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Alexander I'm building a game where I'm trying to simply mark elements in a multidimensional array as "winning" based on some matching logic. So, I'm initially thinking here to pass in my array of arrays to a worker and have it simply return me the same dataset but with "winning" flags flipped for those who match etc. ... have another design pattern I could use? In passing, I refactored my code to not use the class approach which is nice ... I am returning myself copied data, then overriding array1/array2 with it.

Comment: @ChrisAllinson It's not a view controller's job to manage a game board's state. Make a `GameBoard` struct, with mutating functions that flip flags, clears the board, sets the board values, etc.